# Why can't I read a line from file

Tags: c++

I am trying to read the first line of a file.

```
        cout << "File: " << endl;
        string fileName;
        cin >> fileName;
        cout << fileName << endl;

        ifstream infile(fileName);
        string line;

        getline(infile,line,'\n');
        cout << line << endl;
```

I am using CodeBlocks and I have a file named "1.txt" in the same directory as main.cpp.
This file contains 2 lines of thext, but the line variable is always empty. What am I missing here?

Comment: Tried a debugger?

Comment: Have you opened the file ?

Comment: Your code lacks any error handling. Make sure the `ifstream` actually succeeds in opening the file before you then try to read from it. And check that `getline()` actually succeeds in reading a line before you then try to display it. Also, you don't need to explicitly specify `'\n'` to `getline()`, as that is the default delimiter.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I added an error message if(!infile) and it gets triggered. I don't know why, the file name "1.txt" is correct, there is a file named 1.txt in the main directory

Comment: nevermind I forgot that notepad automatically adds the .txt extension so when I namet the file 1.txt (with notepad instead of notepad++) the file got named as 1.txt.txt

Comment: @erdostamasa aside from that, you should not be using relative file paths anyway, always use absolute paths. You don't always know where the calling process' CWD is actually pointing to at any given moment.

Comment: On the contrary; never bake absolute paths into your source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a LOT of searching I finally realized that I used notepad instead of notepad++ and the file got named as `1.txt.txt`
Leaving this answer if anyone has the same problem in the future.

Comment: Note that it is a good pratice to check if the stream is open: `if(not stream.is_open()) { throw MyErrorType(); }`. You should pretty much do something like that with every single IO-process of any type that does not throw by itself.